# Getting this error on precompiling assets: TypeError: couldn't digest ActiveSupport::StringInquirer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I'm a relatively new Rails programmer, and when I try to precompile assets (or even run the server sometimes), I get this error:

```
    TypeError: couldn't digest ActiveSupport::StringInquirer

    /Users/Lucia/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:83:in `digest'
    /Users/Lucia/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:55:in `block in load'
    /Users/Lucia/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:312:in `block in fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1560:in `each'
    org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:1016:in `each_with_index'
   /Users/Lucia/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:308:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
   /Users/Lucia/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
```

...

I've tried turning off digesting in development, and have tried running the rake task with the `RAILS_ENV` flag pointing to development, but with no results.

I've tried looking this issue on google, and can't seem to find anything relevant.

I'm running `jRuby 9.0.5.0` and `rails 4.2.5.2`.

Comment: I am getting the same error on my rspec and I have no idea why :( thx rails 4

Comment: Was running into this too today (rspec), not yet sure what the root cause is, but when I delete `tmp/cache/assets` and run `./bin/spring stop` and then run the specs it works _Edit:_ at least in our case it was caused by branch switching & re-bundling

Comment: Deleting tmp/cache/assets seems to actually work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to kick off these commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:clean
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I faced same issue in production while deploying using Capistrano 3. If used first two steps with  `RAILS_ENV=production` in production server and then run `cap production deploy` from local machine. Don't forget to stop apache(or any webserver) and passenger(or any application server)

Answer (score 7):

For development environment, just remove `tmp/cache/assets/` path

`$ rm -rf tmp/cache/assets/`